# Поиск по меню независимо от регистра

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код. Он ищет прямо в меню и отфильтровывает результаты. Но если пишешь город с маленькой буквы,то он ничего не находит. Как сделать, чтобы независимо от регистра искал город?

```js
        jQuery("document").ready(function($){
 
$(".x-drop-down__value").click(function(event) {
  toggleMenu();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
 
$('.xx1').click(function() {
  $('.x-drop-down__value').html($(this).text());
  toggleMenu();
});
 
function toggleMenu() {
  let menu = $(".x-drop-down__dropped");
  if (!menu.hasClass('active')) {
    window.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
  }
  menu.toggleClass("active");
}
 
function closeMenu() {
  $(".x-drop-down__dropped").removeClass("active")
}
 
$('.x-drop-down__dropped').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
 
 
$('.x-input__field').on('input', function() { 
  let search = $(this).val();
  searchData(search);
});
 
function searchData(search) {
  let towns = $('.xx1');
  towns.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(search) === -1) {
      $(this).addClass('item_hide');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('item_hide');
    }
  });
}
 
});
```

```css
.xx1 {display:block !important}
.xx1.item_hide {display:none !important}
li {list-style:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <ul style="max-height: 420px;">
            <div class="b-order-prepare__field">
                <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="dd_widget">               
                    <div class="x-drop-down__dropped">
                        <div class="x-drop-down__list js-dropdown">
                            <div class="x-drop-down__search">
                                <div class="x-input x-input_size_s">
                                    <span class="x-drop-down__value b-order-prepare__field">Откуда</span><input type="text" class="x-input__field" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/arhangelsk/" class="first xx1">Архангельск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/astrahan/" class="xx1">Астрахань</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/barnaul/" class="xx1">Барнаул</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/belgorod/" class="xx1">Белгород</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/bryansk/" class="xx1">Брянск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/velikij-novgorod/" class="xx1">Великий Новгород</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/vladivostok/" class="xx1">Владивосток</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/volgograd/" class="xx1">Волгоград</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/vologda/" class="xx1">Вологда</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/voronezh/" class="xx1">Воронеж</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/ekaterinburg/" class="xx1">Екатеринбург</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/izhevsk/" class="xx1">Ижевск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/irkutsk/" class="xx1">Иркутск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kazan/" class="xx1">Казань</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kaluga/" class="xx1">Калуга</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kemerovo/" class="xx1">Кемерово</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kirov/" class="xx1">Киров</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kostroma/" class="xx1">Кострома</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/krasnodar/" class="xx1">Краснодар</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/krasnoyarsk/" class="xx1">Красноярск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kurgan/" class="xx1">Курган</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kursk/" class="xx1">Курск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/lipetsk/" class="xx1">Липецк</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/magnitogorsk/" class="xx1">Магнитогорск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/moskva/" class="xx1">Москва</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/moskovskaya-oblast/" class="xx1">Московская область</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/murmansk/" class="xx1">Мурманск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/naberezhnye-chelny/" class="xx1">Набережные Челны</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/nizhnevartovsk/" class="xx1">Нижневартовск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/nizhnij-novgorod/" class="xx1">Нижний Новгород</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/novosibirsk/" class="xx1">Новосибирск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/orel/" class="xx1">Орел</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/orenburg/" class="xx1">Оренбург</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/penza/" class="xx1">Пенза</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/perm/" class="xx1">Пермь</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/petrozavodsk/" class="xx1">Петрозаводск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/pskov/" class="xx1">Псков</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/rostov/" class="xx1">Ростов</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/rostov-na-donu/" class="xx1">Ростов-на-Дону</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/ryazan/" class="xx1">Рязань</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/samara/" class="xx1">Самара</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/sankt-peterburg/" class="xx1">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При поиске приведите строки в нижний регистр `.toLowerCase()`

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
 
$(".x-drop-down__value").click(function(event) {
  toggleMenu();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
 
$('.xx1').click(function() {
  $('.x-drop-down__value').html($(this).text());
  toggleMenu();
});
 
function toggleMenu() {
  let menu = $(".x-drop-down__dropped");
  if (!menu.hasClass('active')) {
    window.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
  }
  menu.toggleClass("active");
}
 
function closeMenu() {
  $(".x-drop-down__dropped").removeClass("active")
}
 
$('.x-drop-down__dropped').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
 
 
$('.x-input__field').on('input', function() { 
  let search = $(this).val();
  searchData(search);
});
 
function searchData(search) {
  let towns = $('.xx1');
  towns.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
      $(this).addClass('item_hide');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('item_hide');
    }
  });
}
 
});
```

```css
.xx1 {display:block !important}
.xx1.item_hide {display:none !important}
li {list-style:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <ul style="max-height: 420px;">
            <div class="b-order-prepare__field">
                <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="dd_widget">               
                    <div class="x-drop-down__dropped">
                        <div class="x-drop-down__list js-dropdown">
                            <div class="x-drop-down__search">
                                <div class="x-input x-input_size_s">
                                    <span class="x-drop-down__value b-order-prepare__field">Откуда</span><input type="text" class="x-input__field" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/arhangelsk/" class="first xx1">Архангельск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/astrahan/" class="xx1">Астрахань</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/barnaul/" class="xx1">Барнаул</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/belgorod/" class="xx1">Белгород</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/bryansk/" class="xx1">Брянск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/velikij-novgorod/" class="xx1">Великий Новгород</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/vladivostok/" class="xx1">Владивосток</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/volgograd/" class="xx1">Волгоград</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/vologda/" class="xx1">Вологда</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/voronezh/" class="xx1">Воронеж</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/ekaterinburg/" class="xx1">Екатеринбург</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/izhevsk/" class="xx1">Ижевск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/irkutsk/" class="xx1">Иркутск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kazan/" class="xx1">Казань</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kaluga/" class="xx1">Калуга</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kemerovo/" class="xx1">Кемерово</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kirov/" class="xx1">Киров</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kostroma/" class="xx1">Кострома</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/krasnodar/" class="xx1">Краснодар</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/krasnoyarsk/" class="xx1">Красноярск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kurgan/" class="xx1">Курган</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/kursk/" class="xx1">Курск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/lipetsk/" class="xx1">Липецк</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/magnitogorsk/" class="xx1">Магнитогорск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/moskva/" class="xx1">Москва</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/moskovskaya-oblast/" class="xx1">Московская область</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/murmansk/" class="xx1">Мурманск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/naberezhnye-chelny/" class="xx1">Набережные Челны</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/nizhnevartovsk/" class="xx1">Нижневартовск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/nizhnij-novgorod/" class="xx1">Нижний Новгород</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/novosibirsk/" class="xx1">Новосибирск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/orel/" class="xx1">Орел</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/orenburg/" class="xx1">Оренбург</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/penza/" class="xx1">Пенза</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/perm/" class="xx1">Пермь</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/petrozavodsk/" class="xx1">Петрозаводск</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/pskov/" class="xx1">Псков</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/rostov/" class="xx1">Ростов</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/rostov-na-donu/" class="xx1">Ростов-на-Дону</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/ryazan/" class="xx1">Рязань</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/samara/" class="xx1">Самара</a></li>
                            <li><a href="uslugi/gruzoperevozki/sankt-peterburg/" class="xx1">Санкт-Петербург</a></li>
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо,все работает как надо!